# Hashmap return value by other hashmap keys

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have two hashmaps one is containing keys and other is containing key with object value.

Here are my two maps and its value

1st one is:

> newProdList = [18=, 2=, 21=1099887, 5=, 22=1099888, 7=, 14=]

and 2nd one is:

> oldList =  [2=Stock [location=AAQ-08-2, stockQty=150,
>   productCode=null, productName=Emergence Men's Running Shoes,
>   division=Shoes, category=Running], 3=Stock [location=AAR-01-1,
>   stockQty=192, productCode=19234402, productName=Men's Running Shoes
>   19234402, division=Shoes, category=Running], 4=Stock
>   [location=BAN-08-1, stockQty=190, productCode=19108206,
>   productName=Carson 2 New Core Men?s Running Shoes, division=Shoes,
>   category=Running] , 21 =Stock [location=BAN-08-1, stockQty=190,
>   productCode=19108206, productName=Carson 2 New Core Men?s Running
>   Shoes, division=Shoes, category=Running]]

I want to iterate newProductList and use there keys in oldList that generate List of objects.

It is simply done by this:

```
List<Stock> stocks = new ArrayList<>(); 
for(Entry<?, ?> e: newProductList.entrySet()){
   Stock s = (Stock) oldProdList.get(e.getKey());
   stocks.add(s);
}

System.out.println(stocks);
```

But I want to use Stream api.

Comment: Unrelated comment: You could choose to iterate over `newProductList.keySet()` in order to simplify your code slightly.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not just a translation service for procedural to functional code. "But I want to use Stream api." Great, so go and learn how to use it: https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams

Comment: @HenrikAastedSørensen - yeah that is also possible but below comment is only given for without stream Api . I want to use Stream API for it.

Comment: @Michael- I have Search so many links regarding my question but I didnt found any solution thats why I ask this in stackoverflow . and I have also use this  https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams link before asking this question

Comment: @Zenny I know. The comment was meant for when you see that the stream-solution is likely to be unreadable and return to the nice, readable code you included in the question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're only using the keys of `newProductList` I'd suggest iterating over `keySet()` instead.

You then could do something like this:

```
List<Stock> stocks = newProductList.keySet().stream() //stream over the keys
                        .map(oldProdList::get) //map by calling get() on the old list
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull) //remove nulls
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()); //build the result list
```

Here we iterate over the keys, map them by doing a lookup, filter on non-null results (in case the lookup fails) and collect the result.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the entrySet to get the corresponding key from newProdList in oldList and set the value from this entry from oldList in newProdList.

More reading here about Map [Entry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html)

```
Map<String,String> newProdList = new HashMap<>();
newProdList.put("18", null);
newProdList.put("2", null);
newProdList.put("21", "1099887");
newProdList.put("5", null);
newProdList.put("22", "1099888");
newProdList.put("7", null);
newProdList.put("14", null);
Map<String,String> oldList = new HashMap<>();
oldList.put("2", "Stock [location=AAQ-08-2, stockQty=150, productCode=null, productName=Emergence Men's Running Shoes, division=Shoes, category=Running]");
oldList.put("3", "Stock [location=AAR-01-1, stockQty=192, productCode=19234402, productName=Men's Running Shoes 19234402, division=Shoes, category=Running]");
oldList.put("4", "Stock [location=BAN-08-1, stockQty=190, productCode=19108206, productName=Carson 2 New Core Men?s Running Shoes, division=Shoes, category=Running]");
oldList.put("21", "Stock [location=BAN-08-1, stockQty=190, productCode=19108206, productName=Carson 2 New Core Men?s Running Shoes, division=Shoes, category=Running]");
newProdList.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> e.setValue(oldList.get(e.getKey())));
```

More explanation with this nice schema, as requested.

[image: map]

Comment: @Michael Added some schema for you.